# TabBar Segue when selecting row in table view controller

Tags: core-data, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I already have a segue set in place in my table view controller for an add button press. Now I want to have another segue for when the user selects on the newly added object. My code looks like this so far:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Vehicle Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting RootViewController as a delegate of AddViewController");

        AddViewController *addViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        addViewController.delegate = self;
        addViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
```

I think I will need to add an else if next to take care of the tab bar segue but don't know how to do that.

Also the tab bar view is just there to show the two tabs so I don't believe I will preform the segue with the reference to core data.

Thanks in advance.!

[My storyboard flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgKBJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to pass value to the next view controller or do any actions that need to done before performing the segue, but just display the tab bar then you don't need to add anything in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. If you do have to do something when performing the segue add and else condition as there is only two segues and write your code inside the else block.

Comment: Ok Thanks I'll try adding the else block.

Comment: After thinking about it more. Would it work if I made another if statement calling out the other segue way identifier? Do you know if there are special segues for tab bar controllers?

Comment: You can add an if also as long as it take does the job. And no, there is no special segues for tab bar controllers.